# Needs to update the value from firebase remote config to my plist

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

In my firebase remote config i have an parameter called :

```
"uniquId" = {[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,14]}
```

i created one plist : `FireStoreRemoteConfig`.

Now I need to fetch the values form firebase remote config, and needs to store the values in plist and I need to use that array values inside my application.

in my `appdelegate` :

```
import FirebaseRemoteConfig
 func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
setUpAppRemoteConfig()
}
func setUpAppRemoteConfig()
    {
        remoteConfig = RemoteConfig.remoteConfig()
        let remoteConfigSettings = RemoteConfigSettings(developerModeEnabled: true)
        remoteConfig.configSettings = remoteConfigSettings
        remoteConfig.setDefaults(fromPlist: "FireStoreRemoteConfig")
        fetchConfig()
    }
 func fetchConfig() {
        print("fetched from firestore")
        let DataVal = remoteConfig[sampleURLConfigKey].stringValue
        print(DataVal)

    }
```

in my plist file, I create an array with parameter name `uniquId` with empty values.

Now every time when I launch my app. I need to get the values from firestore and update to my plist. So that I can use those values inside my application.

Now the values is not coming when i print `print(DataVal)` in `func fetchConfig() {`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on right track. Only small code is missing in your `fetchConfig()`. You not yet fetch the values or data from remote config.

Your updated code should look like :

```
func fetchConfig() {

        // You can give your required duration
        var expirationDuration = 3600
        if remoteConfig.configSettings.isDeveloperModeEnabled {
            expirationDuration = 0
        }

        remoteConfig.fetch(withExpirationDuration: TimeInterval(expirationDuration)) { (status, error) -> Void in
            if status == .success {
                print("Config fetched!")
                self.remoteConfig.activateFetched()
            } else {
                print("Config not fetched")
                print("Error \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            }
            let DataVal = self.remoteConfig[self.sampleURLConfigKey].stringValue
            // You can print and check your  DataVal.



        }
```

Check this  : [Firebase Remote Config iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/ios?authuser=2#build_and_run_the_quickstart_sample)